# Define a generic type with a class object at runtime

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Is it possible to declare the type of a generic using a class object?

For instance, I would like to do something like this:

```
Class returnType = theMethod.getReturnType();

AttributeComponent<returnType> attComponent;

attComponent = new AttributeComponent<returnType>(returnType, attName);
attributeComponents.put(methodName.substring(3), attComponent);
```

Now I know obviously this is incorrect, but is there a way to achieve this?

EDIT: explaining a little bit

I'm using reflection to go through all getters and then generate a UI element for each property (the AttributeComponent class, which has a JComponent element and a JLabel). I would like to use generics in order to create a getValue() method that would return an object of the property type.

Comment: You can not do that. As `returnType` is variable and variables can not be used as Generic Parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if there is a way to compile something like that, but it has little value.

Think that thanks to **type erasure**, the compiled classes do not use the Generics information. That is, doing a `Set<String> a = new Set<String>();` is useful for checking the use of `a` at compile time, but not at runtime.

So, you want to instantiate a Generic whose type will be only known at runtime, but at runtime it will not be used.

Answer (score 2):

I would say this can be achieved by defining the method return type as generic; but you need to pass the actual type as a class argument to use it like you've shown:

```
<T> T yourMethod(Class<T> returnType) {
    // use <T> as generic and returnType to refer to the actual T class
    /* ... */ new AttributeComponent<T>(returnType, attName);
}
```

---

It would be also useful to see the larger context for what you're trying to do. If you want `AttributeComponent.getValue()` to return some generic type `T` (which is the method return type), that's completely useless unless you know each method return type at compile time, otherwise `T` will be nothing more than an `Object`. In my example above, you call `yourMethod` with a class that you already know and the same type will be returned (or some `AttributeComponent` of that type or whatever).

Comment: How does that solve my problem? I am trying to define the AttributeComponent generic type at run-time, if that is even possible (which @Vash already stated it isnt). I edited the original post for further info on what I'm trying to achieve)

Comment: Long story short, you can **not** use a class reference as a generic type. If you need both the class ref and the generic in a particular context, you need to pass them both to that method as in my example *or* you need to do it unsafely (keep the generic and cast the return type obtained via reflection to `Class<T>`).